# How to define main method to run Java program?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I want to run following code in `Eclipse` as `Java Application` and it requires main method to define. At all tries to do it myself was receiving a message:

> method TemperatureNormalizer() is undefiened for the type TemperatureNormalizer

Could you please help me to write it correctly?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TemperatureNormalizer {
   private double[] data;

   public TemperatureNormalizer(double[] list) {
       data = list;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       TemperatureNormalizer();
   }

   public double getAdjustedAverage() {
       double max = getMax();
       double min = getMin();
       double sum = getSum();

       int insertAt = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

           if (data[i] == max || data[i] == min) {
               for (int j = i; j > insertAt; j--) { 
                   data[j] = data[j - 1];
               }
               data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length - 1);
           }    
       }
       return (sum - max - min) / data.length;
   }

   public double getMax() {
        double current = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] > current) {
                current = data[i];
            }
        }
        return current;
    }

    public double getMin() {
        double current = data[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] < current) {    
                current = data[i];  
            }   
        }
        return current;
    }

    public double getSum() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double d : data) {
            sum = sum + d;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to construct the instance of TemperatureNormalizer , so in the main method add `TemperatureNormalizer temperatureNormalizer = new TemperatureNormalizer();` then on a new line call the method`temperatureNormalizer .getAdjustedAverage()`

Answer (score 1):

In your main method, initialize your object with: TemperatureNormalizer temperatureNormalizer = new TemperatureNormalizer ();

Also, your class TemperatureNormalizer  has a constructor which expects an array of Double. Either give an array in your main method or create an extra constructor that doesn't take a parameter.

```
public TemperatureNormalizer()
{
  // do stuff (or not)
}
```

Comment: Thank you guyes, for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create Object of the class in the main method. Already you have created Parameterized constructor, so the compiler won't create a default constructor. You have to code for that.

   ```
   public TempratureNormalizer(){
    // implementation here...
   }

   TempratureNormalizer TempNorm = new TempratureNormalizer();
   ```
2. If you're calling Parameterized constructor that is

   ```
   TempratureNormalizer(double[] list)
   ```

   then the main method should be

   ```
   double[] list = {2.0,3.45,1.09} // give your dynamic values
   TempratureNormalizer TempNorm = new TempNormailzer(list);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a test class (for example) which will contain all your actions:

```
class Test{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        TemperatureNormalizer temperatureNormalizer = new TemperatureNormalizer();
   }  
}
```

If all your classes are in the same folder the compiler will have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run this program then change  main method in the program as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       double  a1[] = {1,2,3,4};
       TemperatureNormalizer temp = new TemperatureNormalizer(a1);
       System.out.println("Avg:" + temp.getAdjustedAverage());
   }
```

It will give output:

```
Avg: 1.6666666666666667
```

Comment: Are there any simplier ways to make run configuration in eclipse for the program, which has no main method?

Comment: you need main method to run your Java Program. Its not possible to run without main method because execution will start from main method only.